# C/C++ ini file parser library

Tags: library, c++, cross-platform, c, parser

I'm trying to find a simple C/C++ library to parse ini configuration files.

It should:

- have tests
- be small (e.g. a .h file and a .cpp file)
- be easy to use ("standard" ini file parsing is sufficient)
- be cross-platform and cross-compiler
- have error checking, possibly exception-less
- be released under a permissive license (MIT/BSD is OK, GPL is not)

Python has ConfigParser, which is pretty straightforward. I like it.

I've checked Boost, and would like to avoid that (too many dependencies).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Boost's [program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/program_options.html) supports INI files (or at least INI-like fileS), see [this section](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idm45555218313840) of the docs.

Comment: Note that there's not **the** INI file format. We have 3 different INI file formats in our company alone - and they're all incompatible to the Microsoft format (*facepalm*)

Comment: For eyars now, I have been very happy with https://github.com/ndevilla/iniparser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could find is [inih](https://github.com/benhoyt/inih). The C++ interface is minimal, but it works.

Features:

- similar to Python's ConfigParser (has Get, GetInteger, ...)
- it's small, two files .cpp and .h
- cross-compiler
- exception-less errors
- permissive license (BSD)

Lacks:

- functions for creating .ini files
- functions to get all sections or all fields at once, but there's [a fork](https://github.com/Blandinium/inih) for that

Answer (score 2):

Modern and cross-platform library is also [inicpp](https://github.com/SemaiCZE/inicpp). It has pretty good test support, is easy to use and one of the greatest features is schema validation (with full type safety). It's not big, but it's more than one .h and .cpp file. License is MIT.

Comment: If I can include a header for basic stuff, it's OK. Requiring support for C++14 is definitely overkill, though.